# Determing how many consecutive fields in an array are empty

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with variables like: 
`$shippingtimearr = array("", "1630", "1530", "1530", "1530", "", "");`
 Each field in this array represents a weekday. 
 I need to determine how many consecutive fields are empty depending on the day ("starting field"). 
 For example: 
If the start is `$shippingtimearr[5]` it should return `3` since next "Monday" (`$shippingtimearr[0]`) is `NULL`.
If the start is an array value that is not `NULL`, it should return `0`;

I tried creating a "for" loop like this:

```
for( $i = 2; $shippingtimearr[$i] = 0; $i++ ) {
            $counter++;
         }
```

But it didn't work and obviously, this would not account for the fact that a "week" should be looped again to see if the first days next week are "`NULL`".

Comment: "consecuentive" means "one after another" .. I think you just need the total number

Comment: Are the values you mentioned really `NULL` or just empty strings `""`?

Comment: that's a good beginning, but beware, the second part of a `for` loop is a condition (it should be `==` instead of `=`). following your idea, you are allowed to manipulate the value of `$i` in the loop to achieve what you want, just be sure to get out of the loop in all the cases

Comment: I strongly suspect, you have misunderstood your homework :P

Comment: I don't need just the total number. This will determine how long a delivery will take depending on which day the order is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody seemed to understand exactly what I was looking for, I will post a solution I came up with myself using a "while" loop:

```
$counter = 0;
$shippingtimearr = ["", "1630", "1530", "1530", "1530", "", ""];
$start = 3;

while ($shippingtimearr[$start++] == NULL) {
    ++$counter;
    if ($start > 6) $start = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$shippingtimearr = array("", "1630", "1530", "1530", "1530", "", "");
$contains_empty = count($shippingtimearr) - count(array_filter($shippingtimearr));
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for some simpler answer like

```
<?php
$shippingtimearr = array("", "1630", "1530", "1530", "1530", "", "");
$counter = 0;
for($i=0;$i<count($shippingtimearr);$i++){
    if($shippingtimearr[$i]=="")
        $counter++;
}
echo $counter;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_count_values(), [check the live demo](https://eval.in/797072)

```
<?php

$shippingtimearr = array("", "1630", "1530", "1530", "1530", "", "");
print_r(array_count_values($shippingtimearr)['']);
```